# Why do I get a BootstrapMethodError when trying to call a super class's protected method using method reference from an inner class?

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8, given a super class `Super` in package `a` and a sub class `Sub` in package `b`, who has an inner class `SubInner`:

```java
// Super.java
package a;

public abstract class Super {
   private long value;
   protected final void setValue(long value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}

//Sub.java
package b;

public class Sub extends Super {
  public void foo() {
    new SubInner().foo();
  }
  private class SubInner {
    void foo() {
      Optional.of(1L).ifPresent(Sub.this::setValue); // Will throw IllegalAccessError at runtime.
      Optional.of(1L).ifPresent(t -> setValue(t)); // However, lambda works.
      setValue(1L); // also works.
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, why method reference fails to work in this case while normal method call have access to super class method `setValue`?

Plus, if I try to do `Sub.super::setValue`, the code doesn't compile and the error seems to be in-line with the runtime error: `setValue` has protected access in `a.Super`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method a.Super.setValue(J)V from class b.Sub$SubInner
    at b.Sub$SubInner.foo(Sub.java:14)
    at b.Sub.foo(Sub.java:10)
    at b.Sub.main(Sub.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method a.Super.setValue(J)V from class b.Sub$SubInner
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1394)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandles.java:1750)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkMethodHandleConstant(MethodHandleNatives.java:477)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It very much looks like [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8138667), which is fixed...

I don't have java-9 locally to confirm that it is indeed fixed in java-9 as the bug states; but works just fine under java-11 and java-12. It would not be the first time there are anomalies in how a lambda/method references are treated by `javac/java`; usually a lambda is a workaround for the method reference and vice-versa.

Comment: yep, that clears things up. added the stack trace to the question as well. it matches the one from that bug.

Comment: I can confirm that it works when being compiled with JDK 9. When using `--release 8`, the compiled code will even work with Java 8. This also applies to `Sub.super::setValue`, which does not even compile under JDK 8, but will run when being compiled with JDK 9 or newer with `--release 8`. In contrast, the code compiled with JDK 8 will fail under all releases at runtime, though, JDK 11 will provide a simplified stack trace showing an `IllegalAccessError` at `b.Sub$SubInner.foo(Sub.java:14)`.